# Cannot Parse JSON using retrofit and use listView

Tags: android, json, listview, retrofit

I am try to parse this [Json](https://newsapi.org/v1/sources?language=en&category=technology) array from this site [NewsApi](https://newsapi.org/) and display it in a listView.When I run the app nothing is displaying.Here is my code.What am doing wrong?.I have tried to debug the problem to no avail.

public class NewsApiClient {

```
public static String API_BASE_URL = "https://newsapi.org/v1/";
```

public static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

```
public static Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()
        );

public static Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();

NewsApiClient client = retrofit.create(NewsApiClient.class);
```

}

calling the endpoint?

```
 public interface NewsApiInterface {
    //endpoint
        @GET("sources")
        Call <SourcesResponse> getTechSources(
                @Query("language") String language,
                @Query("category") String category)
    }
```

I am only using the name,description and category attributes.

```
 public class Source {

        @SerializedName("id")
        public String id;

        @SerializedName("name")
        public String name;

        @SerializedName("description")
        public String description;

        @SerializedName("url")
        public String url;

        @SerializedName("category")
        public String category;

        @SerializedName("language")
        public String language;

        @SerializedName("country")
        public String country;


    }


 public class SourcesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        Context context;
        List<Source> sourceList;

        public SourcesAdapter( Context context,List<Source> sourceList){
            this.context = context;
            this.sourceList = sourceList;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return sourceList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return sourceList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sources_list,null);
            Source currentsource = sourceList.get(position);

            TextView sourcesName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sources_name);
            TextView sourcesDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sources_description);
            TextView sourcesCategory = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sources_category);

            sourcesName.setText(currentsource.name);
            sourcesDescription.setText(currentsource.description);
            sourcesCategory.setText(currentsource.category);



            return convertView;
        }
    }


public class SourcesFragment extends Fragment {

ListView listView;
    public SourcesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        //
        //instance of the adapter to this listview
        View  view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sources, container, false);
        listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_view_sources) ;


        getSources();
        return view;


    }

        public void getSources(){
            Retrofit retrofit = NewsApiClient.builder.build();

            NewsApiInterface newsApiInterface = retrofit.create(NewsApiInterface.class);

            Call<SourcesResponse> sourcesCall = newsApiInterface.getTechSources("en", "technology");
            sourcesCall.enqueue(new Callback<SourcesResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<SourcesResponse> call, Response<SourcesResponse> response) {

                    List<Source> sources = response.body().sources;
                    SourcesAdapter sourcesAdapter = new SourcesAdapter(getContext(),sources);
                    listView.setAdapter(sourcesAdapter);

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<SourcesResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });



        }

    }


public class SourcesResponse {    

    @SerializedName("status")     
    public String status;         

    @SerializedName("sources")    

   public List<Source> sources;   

}

  I have created 3 fragments,the sources fragment is one of them.On the sources fragment i only want to display sources with technology.                            
                      Thank you in advance!
```

Comment: "I have tried to debug the problem to no avail."
Did your debugging attempts yield a LogCat by any chance?

Comment: @Ascorbin, yes it did.

Answer (score 0):

In your retrofit's onResponse callback method, you are accessing sources list like `response.body().sources`. Instead of this in the `SourcesResponse` , add a getter and setter for sources like this

```
public List<SourcesResponse> getSources() {
    return sources;
}

public void setSources(List<SourcesResponse> sources) {
    this.sources = sources;
}
```

Now go to your onResponse callback of retrofit and change

```
response.body().sources
```

to

```
response.body().getSources()
```